# WebGL Earth Cross-Origin Error

Tags: google-app-engine, leaflet, maptiler

Custom map tiles do not load in WebGL Earth from App Engine.  The error message says `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` - but I'm requesting the tiles from the same domain.  You can see the problem in split-screen at [bangmaps.com](http://bangmaps.com) How do I fix this?

```
API.tileLayer('http://example.com/img/pop/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
```

My first attempt to fix the problem (did not work):

app.yaml

```
- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

Comment: Who voted this question down?  This deals with a valid, hard-to-debug problem that other people are likely to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears App Engine only adds 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for requests that are prefixed by 'www.'

I changed this line:

```
API.tileLayer('http://example.com/img/pop/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
```

to

```
API.tileLayer('http://www.example.com/img/pop/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
```

That fixed the problem.